# Your account does not have permission to create iOS distribution certificates

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to upload my app to testflight. when I upload the app Xcode shows this error:

> your account does not have permission to create ios distribution certificates

[image]

Anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have the paid Apple Developer Program?

Comment: Yes, we have a developer account for Team. In that i one ofthe member

Comment: @Aravi pease check my answer.

Comment: Please refer to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/37412282/5580393] might you get the solution

Comment: @Aravi which page are you talking about?

Answer (score 31):

This seems to be a bug or poorly described feature in iTunes Connect & the Apple Developer portal.

I had a developer that joined my team, initially as a "member", but wasn't able to create certificates, even after giving him admin access. It turns out, that I believe we were only giving him admin access to Itunes connect, but not to the developer page.

The correct fix was to go to the developer portal, click the "People" tab (or go to this URL https://developer.apple.com/account/#/people/), remove his access, then use the Invite as Admins to add him to the account. He then had to go into Xcode and remove his developer account information, add it back in, and then he was finally able to upload builds to Testflight without this error.

Comment: Thanks, Only this much is required now... go into Xcode and remove developer account information, add it back in.

Comment: 2 days ago (13 February 2019) apple merge the rights of member center and app store connect. All my invitation accounts were broken. Anyway your procedure still works in 2019... It's such a pain with certificates, provision profiles etc.

Answer (score 8):

This should be the user permission issue. Please note that only user with **Team Agent** role has permission to generate certificates for distribution of app outside the App Store. I believe, you are not in **Team Agent** role. Please double check your permissions.

You can even generate a Certificate Signing Request and send it to your Team Agent. Get back the created certificate from the Team Agent and use it to sign apps.

Comment: you should be Team Agent to generate certificates for distribution of app outside the App Store.

Comment: Otherwise, generate a Certificate Signing Request and send it to your Team Agent. Get back the created certificate from the Team Agent and use it to sign apps.

Comment: I want to upload testflight only. In the apple documentation it shows developer can upload builds

Answer (score 5):

Based on your comment "Yes, we have a developer account for Team" I am guessing that what you have is an Enterprise Developer account. If you have a Enterprise DA you cannot upload to the apple store/test-flight. You will need to create a personal developer account for that. Enterprise accounts are only good for in house testing and not for external. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: This was my issue, it used to default to enterprise deployment but after xcode 8 it doesn't seem to (or I was dumb and just missed it this time). I hadn't realized I had picked appstore, and we have an enterprise account.

Answer (score 3):

1. Using keychain, export valid certificate on a computer on which iOS distribution signing identity works. You need two files, one is public - `<fileNamePublic>.pem` file, and other is private - `<fileNamePrivate>.p12` file.
2. Put those files in a folder on computer on which you need signing identity to work.
3. Open terminal and browse to the folder you've put them in.
4. First, type: `security import <fileNamePrivate>.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`
5. Then type: `security import <fileNamePublic>.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`
6. Open XCode, go to XCode>preferences>accounts>view details and refresh the apple id you are using
7. You should have signing identities enabled.

Comment: sorry, where I can get the files?

Comment: please check this guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your iTunes Connect account does not have the correct [role](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW24)?

Comment: I am the member of the Team. Can i upload the app to testflight? Or Team agent or Manager can upload?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW24

Comment: Apple documentation shows Developer can upload builds

Comment: It says that managing test flight builds is readonly for developers.

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving similar error and also, I had a permission to create certificate with my account which has developer role. I tried all of the solutions but none of them worked for me. Therefore, I downloaded provisioning profile from developer account and I used that provisioning profile from manual signing when I was archiving to my build then error disappeared.

Comment: This worked for me when nothing else did, June '21! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every thing was good with my account, no permission changed as already it was same email id used to purchase the account. 
I fixed this problem by removing the account from Xcode preferences and again added it. What i did was immediately added credentials in Xcode preferences right after purchasing the account. I should have to wait for Apple to process the order.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this now: `Team Agent` no longer exists.  If your role is `Admin` or `App Manager` you can upload builds and create provisioning profiles, etc.  Note that if you get this error when you upload, then ask for the correct permissions and it *still* doesn't work, quit Xcode and try again!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps your provisioning profile was expired and even after updating it from Apple's developer website, Xcode doesn't try to fetch the new one.

Here's how to solve it:

1. Xcode -> preferences -> accounts
2. Select your Apple ID, and on the right bottom pane select your team and click View Details
3. Under provisioning profile, find your expired profile, right click, and click Move to Trash
4. You should be able to sign and upload your app.

Answer (score -4):

If you are getting the same error...Create the .ipa file and upload to https://www.diawi.com/

you will get an link, which you can share with your client.It's not a solution for your question but it will help you.