# Xcode 10. Your account does not have permission to create iOS App Store provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 10. When I try to upload app to TestFlight I get the following error '**Your account does not have permission to create iOS App Store provisioning profiles.**'

I have '**Admin**' role in Apple Developer Program and I have '**App Manager**' role in App Store Connect (https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev82a173c41)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It has been already discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40670695/3930651

*Admin* role is not sufficient, you need to be the *Team Agent*.

Comment: But what 'Team Agent' role do you mean? From 'Apple Developer Program Team Roles' or from 'App Store Connect Roles'?  https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: Sorry, I have overlooked that you would like to use the TestFlight. This answer was for the Enterprise Distribution. For TestFlight, Admin role should be sufficient. Maybe, try to create distribution provisioning profile on developer portal.

Comment: I dont know why it marked as already answerd , but in my case I had create profile from ```https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list```